# Android OpenGL ES Tutorial

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm running through the tutorial on the Android developer site and I have run through building the environment several times now without getting the "grey screen" that the tutorial indicates should be the result.

Link to the tutorial in question:
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

The program seems to compile and install just fine, but when it runs it "closes unexpectedly."

Here is my code...
Main.java:

```
package com.wiley.openglplayground;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

    class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

        public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

            setRenderer(new MyRenderer());

            setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        }
    }
}
```

MyRenderer.java:

```
package com.wiley.openglplayground;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }

}
```

From what I can tell, the code should work just like it would for them in the tutorial... What am I missing?  Am I not supposed to be able to run it at this stage?

Thanks guys!

Per request, this is the LogCat output:

```
12-27 14:27:05.768: W/ActivityThread(3493): Application com.wiley.openglplayground is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-27 14:27:05.778: I/System.out(3493): Sending WAIT chunk
12-27 14:27:05.878: I/dalvikvm(3493): Debugger is active
12-27 14:27:05.978: I/System.out(3493): Debugger has connected
12-27 14:27:05.978: I/System.out(3493): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-27 14:27:06.179: I/System.out(3493): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-27 14:27:06.379: I/System.out(3493): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-27 14:27:06.579: I/System.out(3493): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-27 14:27:06.779: I/System.out(3493): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-27 14:27:06.979: I/System.out(3493): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-27 14:27:07.180: I/System.out(3493): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-27 14:27:07.380: I/System.out(3493): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-27 14:27:07.580: I/System.out(3493): debugger has settled (1420)
12-27 14:27:07.890: D/libEGL(3493): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-27 14:27:07.890: D/libEGL(3493): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
12-27 14:27:07.900: D/libEGL(3493): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
12-27 14:27:07.900: D/libEGL(3493): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
12-27 14:27:07.950: D/OpenGLRenderer(3493): Enabling debug mode 0
12-27 14:27:08.711: D/dalvikvm(3493): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
12-27 14:28:21.132: D/AndroidRuntime(3493): Shutting down VM
12-27 14:28:21.132: W/dalvikvm(3493): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a601f8)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(GLSurfaceView.java:512)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:533)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1617)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
12-27 14:28:21.252: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 14:28:21.442: I/Process(3493): Sending signal. PID: 3493 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? If yes, can you please add the logcat output with the stacktrace?

Comment: You'll also need to ensure that whatever you are deploying it to supports OpenGL ES 2.0. If you are using the Android emulator you need to select Hardware Acceleration (Emulation Options: Use Host GPU).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, guys!  Added the LogCat output to the question.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to go about posting a stacktrace from Eclipse...  Any tips?

Comment: Oh, I thought I had added this to my previous comment, but I know the device works with OpenGL ES 2.0 since the program downloaded from Google runs fine.  However, in that program, they had gone all the way through drawing the Triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.

I realized that when I was initializing the mGLView variable, I was initializing it with a new GLSurfaceView instead of **My**GLSurfaceView.

Fixed code:

```
package com.wiley.opengles;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this); //This is where the problem was.
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }
}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}
```